# weird answer to sin and cos of pi in python

Tags: python, math, pi, trigonometry

I have faced a really weird problem.
when I want to find sin or cos of some angles, I get strange answers in python interpreter.

```
>>>from math import *
>>>sin(pi)
Out:1.2246467991473532e-16
>>>cos(pi)
Out:-1.0
```

It answered cos correctly but sin was strange.
while pi/2 is reverse.

```
>>>sin(pi/2)
Out: 1.0
cos(pi/2)
Out: 6.123233995736766e-17
```

I'm confused!

Can someone explain what's happening?

> BTW I use canopy and python 2.7.9

Comment: at least you won't have division by zero issues ;) sorry for the joke, i guess the reason is that you should use tau

Comment: For all intents and purposes, those values are zero. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Please go through this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

Comment: Welcome to the world of finite precision arithmetic. When using floating-point, never expect the computations to be exact (sometimes they are "by accident"). Anyway, in most cases the results have a much better accuracy than the data you provide. (Who can measure an angle with less than 10^{-16} error ? This is a must-read: "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic".

Answer (score 1):

I think the output to the following will answer your question. Your output isn't wrong, it's just the side effect of using computers for calculations.

```
print "sin(pi) = %.2f\ncos(pi/2) = %.2f" % (sin(pi), cos(pi/2))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You basically just say that an approximation with two decimals of some very small value will be 0.00

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Exactly. I want the OP to realise that he's getting accurate enough result.